# Biggest variable that is possible to define

Tags: microcontroller, programming

I have a lot of data to storage at very fast speed. I can't send them using serial becouse is too slow. I've tryed to use and external flash memory but due some library problem I can't reach writing speed I need. The only way, I've tryed, that work is to storate data in an array of 8 bit. But i've tested and found that maximum size I can define is 5000 (array[5000];). Now I have 256KB free memory for code on my MCU, and I need to storate 5KB of code and 200KB of data. But I can't define in the code 50 arrays. There's a way that can define an array bigger as I want? There is a way that define my arrays when code is executing?

Comment: I think you will need to find out how much memory you need in RAM and how much you will need in Flash. This will tell you what your requirements will be. According to that, you will need to initialise your variables correctly (it's important if they can be left in an undefined state at the beginning or if they need to be initialized to some specific values)

Comment: Have you considered using a MCU with an external memory bus that you can connect some parallel SRAM to?

Comment: Have you looked into parallel drives to parallel ports. If it's temporary storage, set your Array to more dimensions, an array of array's.

Comment: Which MCU & compiler are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Most micros won't let you write to flash memory by simply declaring an array in it. Instead, there are library functions that you can use to transfer a block of data from RAM to flash. You'll have to look at the details of the micro you're using (which you haven't specified) and its software development tools in order to find out how to do it.

Comment: Not exactly.. In most micros you can declare a **constant** (readonly) array in the program memory, which is readonly, which is stored in flash.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: But you can't *write* to a read-only array.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't confuse the arrays you define in your code for code. They actually go to a data section, especially if you define them globally and don't initialize. If so, then they go into the so called BSS section, which is NOT included into your resulting binary file that you put into the code memory of your MCU. The code produced by the compiler will allocate an area in the data memory (RAM) for both your .data and .bss sections. For the .data section it will fill it with the data stored in the code (flash) memory, while for .bss it will just zero it.

So you actually CAN allocate 50 arrays in your code and they will go into BSS (RAM).

However, it's a very interesting question why you can't allocate more that 5000 bytes in an array. Are you may be trying to allocate an array within a function rather than declaring it globally? In such a case the compiler allocates the array on a stack that indeed may impose any strange limit like 5000 bytes. Please try declaring globally an array of bigger size. Then it should be limited only by your target MCU's RAM size and architecture (address space).